# Manga about WWII in Japan

Tags: barefoot-gen

I bought two volumes of this manga about 10 years ago, but I don't remember much about it. These are some details that I remember:

- I'm not sure but I think it's shounen.
- I don't really like the art, so I can't really tell anything about it, but I know that the art is not really the biggest point of this manga. Or... I was just 10 y/o back then and the art is not like most shounen manga that year so I didn't really like it.
- There's a scene where one boy (I believe he's the main character here) is fighting with his friends, and I think his friends are bullying him, and that boy bites the friend's finger off and eats it later. But he's eating his friend's finger not because he's psycho but because he's poor and wants to eat some meat. That's just how poor he is.
- The boy has at least one little brother.
- One chapter shows when an atomic bomb dropped in Nagasaki or Hiroshima, and almost everyone died there.
- The atomic bomb is shown in the first or second volume of the manga so I think maybe it's a post-apocalypse manga.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The year is a little bit off but I think it's [Hadashi no Gen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barefoot_Gen)

[image]

It's a manga series by Keiji Nakazawa. The series takes place in Hiroshima during the final months of World War II. The main character is a boy named Gen Nakaoka and his family live in poverty. It shows an atomic bomb attack in Hiroshima on first volume, where Gen's father and siblings perished in the fires, but Gen and his mother managed to escape.

> There's a scene where one boy (I believe he's the main character here) is fighting with his friends, and I think his friends are bullying him, and that boy bites the friend's finger off and eats it later

It's probably this, he ate the finger afterward.

[image]

As you can see, the art is not like most shounen manga around 2000. It's because this manga was serialized from 1973 to 1985. It was published at late '90s in my country so I guess there is a possibility that this is the manga you mentioned.